# Finding a linear classifier using data stored in database

Tags: sql, database

My task is as follows: I have a table with columns `X, Y, Class`
 Where x coordinate in Cartesian coordinate system , 
 y coordinate in Cartesian coordinate system 
 and the class of a point e.g. class 1, class 2).
 I need to find a line which divides the plane in such way that points of separate classes resides in two independent parts of the coordinate system. It is my first time with linear classifiers. I am wondering how I can achieve this using just one `select` query - subqueries are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction is that this is not a problem amenable to SQL and you should look up statistical/data analysis software.  The "best" such line is provided by support vector machines (SVM) and you can look it up.

However, if you have lots of time, or very few points, you could try a brute force method.  That is, go through a list of possible lines and see how well they split.

So, assume a line has an equation `y = mx + b`.  Here is a test of a bunch of lines with different slopes.  You can test the side of the line by whether `y - mx + b` is positive or negative.  You then aggregate this for each side and for each category, and use some logic to choose the side for a category.

For this, I'm using SQL Server syntax:

```
with nums as (  -- get a bunch of nums
      select row_number() over (order by null) as n
      from information_schema.columns c
     ),
    m as (
     select n - 10 as m  -- from -10 to 10
     from nums
     where n <= 21
    ),
    b as (
     select n - 10 as b  -- from -10 to 10
     from nums
     where n <= 21
    )
    lines as (
     select m, b
     from m cross join b
    )
select m, b,
       (case when cat1_side1 > cat1_side2 then 'side1' else 'side2'
        end) as cat1_side,
       (case when cat1_side1 > cat1_side2 then cat1_side1 else cat1_side2
        end) as cat1_correct,
      (case when cat1_side1 > cat1_side2 then 'side2' else 'side1'
       end) as cat2_side,  -- force cat2 to the other side
      (case when cat1_side1 > cat1_side2 then cat2_side2 else cat2_side1
       end) as cat2_correct
from (select l.m, l.b, 
             sum(case when p.category = 'cat1' and p.y - (p.x*l.m + l.b) < 0
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) as cat1_side1_cnt,
             sum(case when p.category = 'cat1' and p.y - (p.x*l.m + l.b) > 0
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) as cat1_side2_cnt,
             sum(case when p.category = 'cat2' and p.y - (p.x*l.m + l.b) < 0
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) as cat2_side1_cnt,
             sum(case when p.category = 'cat2' and p.y - (p.x*l.m + l.b) > 0
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) as cat2_side2_cnt,
      from points p cross join
           lines l
      group by l.m, l.b, p.category
     ) lp
order by (cat1_correct + cat2_correct) desc
```

Note that this code chooses the side for category1 and this, in turn, forces the other side for category 2.  You can't choose the best side for each, because the all your data points might be on one side of the line.

Also, this doesn't work for vertical lines, but it comes close.

In putting this together, I am *not* saying that this is the best way to approach this problem.  However, for a smallish number of data points, it might actually work pretty well.